# Why doesn't Java 8's Predicate<T> extend Function<T, Boolean>

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, predicate, java-8

If I wrote the `Predicate` interface, I'd want to encode in the interface the fact that it's just a function that returns a primitive `boolean`, like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> extends Function<T, Boolean> {

    boolean test(T t);

    @Override
    default Boolean apply(T t) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(test(t));
    }
}
```

I was wondering, is there a compelling reason Java 8 API designers chose to keep the `Predicate` completely separate from `Function`? Is there some evidence that they considered doing so and decided against it? I guess similar question goes for all the other 'special' functional interfaces like `Consumer` (could be `Function<T, Void>`), `Supplier` (`Function<Void, T>`) and primitive functions like `IntFunction` (`Function<Integer, T>`).

I haven't thought very deeply and thoroughly about all the ramifications of this, so I'm probably missing something.

EDIT: Some of the answers emphasize the semantic distinction between apply and test. I'm not saying I don't appreciate the distinction, and I agree that it's beneficial to have this distinction. What I don't understand is why a `Predicate` is nevertheless not also a `Function in` the same way as, e.g., a `List` is a `Collection` or `Double` is a `Number`, which is an `Object`.

If `Predicate` (and all the other special generic functional interfaces, such as `Consumer`, `Supplier`, `IntUnaryOperator` etc.) had this relation with `Function`, it would allow one to use it in place where `Function` parameter is expected (what comes to mind is composition with other functions, e.g. calling `myFunction.compose(myPredicate)` or to avoid writing several specialized functions in an API when such auto(un)boxing implementation as described above would be sufficient)

EDIT 2: Looking at openjdk lambda project I found that primitive functional interfaces used to extend `Function` up until [this commit from Brian Goetz on 2012-12-19](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rev/68f1d0672940). I couldn't find specific reasons for the change on any of the lambda-dev or JSR experts group mailing lists around that time.

Comment: @brian-goetz care to give the canonical answer to EDIT 2?

Answer (score 23):

The method in `Predicate<T>` returns `boolean`. The method in `Function<T, Boolean>` returns `Boolean`. They are not the same. Although there is autoboxing, Java methods don't use wrapper classes when primitives would do. Also, there are differences like `Boolean` can be `null` while `boolean` can't.

It's even more different in the case of `Consumer<T>`. The method in `Consumer<T>` has return type `void`, which means it can implicitly return or return using `return;`, but the method in `Function<T, Void>` must return using `return null;` explicitly.

Comment: This doesn't sound convincing. Considering that Java 8 has default methods, couldn't they have easily made `Predicate<T>` extend `Function<T>` and ensure that there was a `default apply` method in Predicate that delegated to `test` ? This way consumers could simply implement `test` while also getting the benefit of a consistent `apply` semantics

Answer (score 13):

There is no need for such a suspicious inheritance hierarchy. These functional interfaces are inter-changable.

```
Function<A,Boolean> f1=…;
Predicate<A>        p1=…;

Predicate<A>        p2=f1::apply;
Function<A,Boolean> f2=p1::test;
```

This works in both directions. So why should there be an inheritance relationship advertising one specific direction?

Answer (score 6):

It is not a direct answer to your question, but for what would you be using it for?

Consider the following scenario: You want to map true/false to the list of values for which it is true respectively false.

With your code you could use:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CustomPredicate<T> extends Function<T, Boolean> {
    boolean test(T value);

    @Override
    default Boolean apply(T t) {
        return test(t);
    }
}
```

---

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("a");
stringList.add("hg");
stringList.add("dsl");
stringList.add("sldi");
stringList.add("ilsdo");
stringList.add("jlieio");
CustomPredicate<String> customPredicate = str -> (str.length() >= 3);
Map<Boolean, List<String>> mapping = stringList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(customPredicate));
```

The following however tells me that they have definately thought about something similar, as they offer the partitioning method:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("a");
stringList.add("hg");
stringList.add("dsl");
stringList.add("sldi");
stringList.add("ilsdo");
stringList.add("jlieio");
Predicate<String> predicate = str -> (str.length() >= 3);
Map<Boolean, List<String>> mapping = stringList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(predicate));
```

Some reasons I can think about are:

- It would not be intuitive to have a `apply()` method available in a `Predicate` where you only expect a `test()` method.
- Functional interfaces are designed to provide only **one** type of basic functionality (excluding chaining or logical operations), in your situation `CustomPredicate` contains two types of functionality. It would only add to confusion.

Comment: Another good reason is that we can avoid unnecessary boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I'm not suggesting replacing the test() method with apply() Auto(un)boxing would only be done when the object is used in a setting where there's no alternative Predicate-based implementation. The function that accepts generic Function<A, ?> could always have a specialized Predicate<A> overload for performance.

Comment: @skiwi My suggestion would only express the same operation in another non-primitive, more generic way. It's not uncommon for classes/interfaces to have methods that are there just to implement a concept at a higher abstraction level (PrimitiveIterator.OfInt extends Iterator and uses boxing; Deque extends Queue and replaces offer() with identical, but more aptly named offerLast)

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion `Function<T, R>` is just the definition of a generic function. If all `FunctionalInterfaces` would implement `Function`, the only abstract method would have to be named `apply()`. In the context of a concrete `FunctionalInterface` like `FilterFile`, the abstract method `boolean accept(File pathname)` is a much better name then `Boolean apply(File)`.

The annotation `@FunctionalInterface` already marks an interface as being intended to be usable as a `FunctionalInterface`. There is no benefit having them all implement a base interface other then processing them in a generic way. I do not see when you would not care about the semantics of a `FunctionalInterface` in advance to make them available to call `apply` for them all.

Comment: I'm not necessarily advocating that all functional interfaces should be replaced with Function. I'm suggesting that the predefined generic functional interfaces might extend Function, which would preserve semantics while allowing additional things, such as processing in a generic (this seems to be a relevant benefit, especially if there are no significant drawbacks)